# How do I apply a String extension to a Func<String>

Tags: c#, extension-methods, func

I have a constructor signature like this

```
public NavigationLink(Func<String> getName, 
                      Func<UrlHelper, String> getURL, 
                      Func<bool> isVisible, 
                      IEnumerable<NavigationLink> subItems)
```

Inside that constructor I am assigning the getName to a property of the containing class

```
GetName = getName
```

I have a string extension that does casing on a string call String.CapitalizeWords();

How do I apply that extension to the Func?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
GetName = () => getName().CapitalizeWords();
```

But why do you need a parameterless function, returning a String instead of the String itself?

Comment: I didn't write this. One of the developers I work with has a thing for all these delegates. I just go /sigh a lot.

Comment: You don’t need the to call the constructor explicitly, i.e. the `new Func<String>` wrapper. Just the lambda is fine.

Answer (score 1):

So is this the signature for the `GetName` property?

```
string GetName{get;set;}
```

If so, I guess all you need to do is

```
GetName=getName().CapitalizeWords();
```

Otherwise if the signature is like this:

```
Func<string> GetName{get;set;}
```

you'd probably need to do

```
GetName=getName;
string caps = GetName().CapitalizeWords();
```

I hope I understood your question :P

Answer (score 0):

It will be there for the results of running getName, not on getName itself.  GetName is a delegate to a function that will return a string; it is not itself a string.  You should be able to do `String CapName = GetName().CapitalizeWords()`.

Comment: Ya. I should have specialized however that the property in the class is not of type String but instead of Func<String>. /sigh much?

Comment: ah, gotcha.  The other guys saw it that way, so you got a good answer.  Wow, that guys does like delegates, doesn't he?

Answer (score 0):

```
GetName = () => getName().CapitalizeWords();
```